# How does Spring Security inject principal into Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I can get the user principal as the below code, but I am puzzled how Spring Security knows to inject the correct principal. Usually, we would pass the args to call a method with parameters. So, where does Spring call the Controller Method with Principal args? Thanks for any help.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping({"/api/user"})
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

Comment: The interface you're looking for is `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`; also read the Spring MVC documentation on how the Dispatcher Servlet works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment says, `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is a strategy interface for resolving method parameters into argument values in the context of a given request. Actually, Principal argument would be resolved in `ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver`. Talk is cheap, and show the source code.

```
@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, @Nullable ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
        NativeWebRequest webRequest, @Nullable WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

    Class<?> paramType = parameter.getParameterType();

    // WebRequest / NativeWebRequest / ServletWebRequest
    if (WebRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType)) {
        if (!paramType.isInstance(webRequest)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Current request is not of type [" + paramType.getName() + "]: " + webRequest);
        }
        return webRequest;
    }

    // ServletRequest / HttpServletRequest / MultipartRequest / MultipartHttpServletRequest
    if (ServletRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType) || MultipartRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType)) {
        return resolveNativeRequest(webRequest, paramType);
    }

    // HttpServletRequest required for all further argument types
    return resolveArgument(paramType, resolveNativeRequest(webRequest, HttpServletRequest.class));
}
```

Now you can see the the key code as **Principal.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType)**, and if you look for furtherly, you can see the code `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to get the actual argument. Ok, that's all, thanks for @chrylis -on strike- comments.

```
@Nullable
private Object resolveArgument(Class<?> paramType, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    //omitted......
    else if (Principal.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType)) {
        Principal userPrincipal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        if (userPrincipal != null && !paramType.isInstance(userPrincipal)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Current user principal is not of type [" + paramType.getName() + "]: " + userPrincipal);
        }
        return userPrincipal;
    }
    //omitted......
}
```

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match with the code. Getting the principal is done by calling `getPrincipal` on the request not using Spring Security. Injecting/getting the principal isn't tied to Spring Security at all.

Comment: Really? I find getting the principal by calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` in the source code.  Which is the class of  `getPrincipal` method?

Comment: That is what Spring Security ultimatly does by integratiing with the http servlet request. Using the principal in your web method has nothing to do with Spring Security. It will just inject the current principal for the http request, which works with and without Spring Security. All in all your answer is actualy confusing.