# Spring Boot + Keycloak: optional auth endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to configure a Spring Boot application with Keycloak to have an endpoint that is **both** accessible for authenticated and unauthenticated users. For authenticated users, I want to return some extra information. Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Principal principal) {
        KeycloakPrincipal keycloakPrincipal = (KeycloakPrincipal) principal;
        if (keycloakPrincipal != null) {
            return "Hello " + keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getPreferredUsername();
        } else {
            return "Hello";
        }

    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = *
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = Hello
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /*
```

So far, I only got it to work for one of both cases. If I protect the endpoint using the security constraint above, the endpoint is only accessible to authenticated users. If I remove the security constraint, the endpoint is accessible for everyone, but then the principal will always be `null`.

Is it possible to achieve the intended behavior?

Comment: What was your guide/tutorial or research? How do following answers help you? [How does Spring Security inject principal into Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751605/how-does-spring-security-inject-principal-into-controller) or [How to get Principal from a Keycloak secured Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586558/how-to-get-principal-from-a-keycloak-secured-spring-boot-application)

Comment: @hc_dev I was following the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter) for the Spring Boot adapter and [a guide on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak#controller).


Note that I'm not using Spring Security, just the Keycloak Spring Adapter. If the endpoint is protected with a security constraint, I'm able to get the principal with the provided code. But then an unauthenticated user cannot access the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `Principal principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`?

I believe the Principal as method parameter is only populated on secured endpoints but am unsure if it would exist in the SecurityContext. If not, you need to add a Filter to add it yourself.

Comment: I'm not using Spring Security, so the `SecurityContextHolder` is not available to me. But indeed, the user principal is only populated on secured endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by calling the `authenticate()` method on the `HttpServletRequest` object. This will trigger the authentication process and will populate the user principal whenever possible. From the [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#authenticate(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)):

> Triggers the same authentication process as would be triggered if the
> request is for a resource that is protected by a security constraint.

To avoid triggering an authentication challenge, I pass in a dummy response object to the `authenticate()` call.